# Laravel + AngularJS CORS not working

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, nginx, cors

I'm making an AngularJS project, right now at `http://localhost` with a laravel backend at `http://api.localhost`, both served by an nginx server.

when making an $http.post request, angular first makes the CORS OPTIONS call, and I've configured my nginx server to respond with the proper headers:

```
    location / {
            add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*";
            add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" "true";
            add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET,POST,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS";
            add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Keep-Alive,User-Agent,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Authorization";
            add_header "Access-Control-Max-Age" "1728000";

            if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                    return 204;
            }


            #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /index.php {

            add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*";
            add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" "true";
            add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET,POST,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS";
            add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Keep-Alive,User-Agent,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Authorization";
            add_header "Access-Control-Max-Age" "1728000";

            if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                    return 204;
            }

           ...
    }
```

My angular module is also configured with:

```
.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
}])
```

The OPTIONS call returns as expected:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Keep-Alive,User-Agent,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET,POST,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Max-Age:1728000
Connection:keep-alive
Date:Mon, 04 Nov 2013 02:14:16 GMT
Server:nginx/1.2.6 (Ubuntu)
```

But the subsequent POST call I make fails with a status of CANCELED and angular throws an error to the JS console:

```
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.localhost/users/accesstokens. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`
```

I stayed up late last night and got this working, but when I tried again today, it was back to square one. Worst kind of problem!

What do?

EDIT: I found the problem, but I still don't understand it. I looked at my nginx access logs, and saw the POST request was in fact hitting the server even though the status was CANCELED. I also saw the response was a 401. After getting my request correct, the response was 201. Still the same CANCELED status. But when I adjusted the status to 200, voila! The request worked as intended.

Is there a reason AngularJS is only accepting a 200 status in a cross-origin request?

Answer (score 0):

Angular.js $http service considers valid any status between 200 and 299 inclusive, you can see it in the $http source code; [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L82) and [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L221) I can't find the status 200 hardcoded anywhere else.

Despite the Chrome console message, the problem could be something that Alistair Robinson [points in this post](http://blog.alistairrobinson.com/angular-http-post-request-takes-minutes-to-complete/) 
Check if your nginx is updated to the latest stable version, and then check if it is sending 'Content-Length' header correctly, if it's not, I'll go with the Alistair solution to manually fill Content-Length header.